# Ensure we don't have over-connected components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, eslint, flowtype

Looking for a way to generate some kind of error if there are things in `connect` that aren't in the props of a component. i.e. you were using some data, and now aren't, it should error and tell you that you're passing in too many props.

I tried to do this with Flow's exact objects, but it wouldn't actually generate errors - not sure why. Then I started writing an eslint plugin that would analyze the props and the types and generate a list of what was connected and not in props. The problem with that is that there is a heap of edge-cases, like Intersections and Spreads that would require a *lot* of digging.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: are you using PropTypes?

Comment: Switch over to TypeScript and have strict typing and interface declarations? :)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice not using PropTypes, am using Flow.

Comment: @jered already using Flow, not that keen to change. Plus, if that works for TS, it should probably work for Flow.

Comment: Please provide live example. As i understood - everything should [work](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN4CGAXGAHYCuAtgEZ4BOAvgNzpQN0AxhgCWcOmChw4YABSV2Ac1oASAKIAPSsIA8hAHwBKcqk59psqrQCMAGjAtaAJk6H0QA)

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without knowing what you've tried. Please provide a [mcve].